# Is it possible using Spring's @ExceptionHandler to get the handler that actually threw the exception?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

It looks like HandlerExceptionResolver provides this functionality:

```
resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
```

I'm assuming "handler" is the handler that threw the exception. Can I get this in @ExceptionHandler, including all of the details that are associated with the request mapping for that handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html), no, you can't. The list of permitted arguments types does not include information about the handler itself.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and thought that might be the case, but I wanted to ask to be sure.